# Difference between http connection request and socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

All:

I am new to node.js and socket.io, and have no idea about how the protocol works. But I am learning.

I got a beginner question about socket.io,if I got code from some tutorial like:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(
        function(request, response){
            console.log("New Connection!");
            fs.readFile(
                "client.html","utf-8", 
                function(err, data){
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                    response.write(data);
                    response.end();
                }
            );
        }
).listen(1337);



var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on(
            'connection',
            function( socket ){
                socket.on(
                        'message_to_server',
                        function(data){
                        io.sockets.emit('message_to_client',{message: data['message']});
                        }
                );
            }
);
```

My question is can someone tells me how this code works? What I am confused is:

It seems like the socket.io just wraps the app,sending and receiving event message and doing callback. But I wonder why those action will not triger app's request event, I put console.log("New Connection!"); inside that callback, and it only displays when I input the server address and press enter in browser, but when I press the send button, it will not display anything?

Here is my client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Out client code here.
            var socketio = io.connect("192.168.1.150:1337");
            socketio.on(
                    'message_to_client',
                    function(data){
                        document.getElementById("chatlog")
                        .innerHTML=
                        ("<hr/>"+data['message']+document.getElementById("chatlog").innerHTML);
                    }
            );

            function sendMessage(){
                var msg = document.getElementById("message_input").value;
                if(msg!=""){
                    socketio.emit("message_to_server", {message:msg});
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="message_input" />
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">SEND</button>
        <div id="chatlog"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code `app` is an http server, and `io` is a websocket server. As you know http server serves http request, whereas websocket server uses websocket protocol. Check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

- http:// is http protocol and https:// is http secure protocol
- ws:// is web socket protocol and  wss:// is web socket secure protocol

What this does

```
var app = http.createServer(
    function(request, response){
        console.log("New Connection!");
```

It starts a http server and executes the given function on every http request. For you, it prints `New Connection` and sends client.html.

What this does

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

It tells the socket server to hook into the http server. It listens on the same address and port as http/https server for websocket connections.

What this does

```
var socketio = io.connect("192.168.1.150:1337");
```

Conencts to websocket server at 192.168.1.150:1337 and uses the socket for communication. You say nothing shows up when you click send, are you using correct address? Try this, it automagically gets the address (in use):

```
var socketio = io.connect("");
```

Comment: I tried io.connect(""). It is still same, when I input some string into that text input box and press send, the serverside only print the message infomation, but it did not print out NEW Connection! Only when I refresh the page or press enter in address bar, the server can print out New Connection? I wonder: Is it because the websocket request can not trigger the app httpserver's request function?

Comment: It seems client cannot connect open websocket connection. I am able to run your code on my local machine. Where are you deploying your server ?

Comment: I just use node itself( node ./main.js), I can run this code too, the chating function works very well! But it just can not print out "New Connection" everytime I press send button. I do not know if this is my wrong understanding about how the websocket server works.

Comment: OK I misunderstood your question. If you want to print "New Connection" when ever you press send button, then it should be inside socket.on('message_to_server', function(data){ io.sockets.emit('message_to_client',{message: data['message']}); //here });